# Error trying to create Synchronization Connection

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

I'm trying to create a Synchronization Connection by going to `Central Administration > Manage Service Applications > User Profile Service Application > Configure Synchronization Connections`.

When I click `'Create New Connection'` I get the following error:

> 'Cannot navigate to the requested page while User Profile Synchronization is running. Please wait for the current
>   Synchronization run to finish.'

So, then I go to Timer Job Status and click `'Running'`, and it shows no jobs running. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the User Profile Syncronization Service on the Services on Server Page in Central Admin `http://centralAdminURL:port/_admin/Server.aspx`

If the UPSA is stuck on starting, and not stopping (or starting), you can force stop the service using PowerShell:

```
>Get-SPServiceInstance -Server "Servername"
>Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity "GUID of Service"
```

Run the first line, copy the GUID of UPSA and run the second line with the GUID. Continue to configure Syncronization Connections in Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue seems to occur when the User Profile Service is stuck by some other process or process overlaps (You would see the User Profile Synchronization Service stopped in System Settings->Manage Services on Server Section),

Try restarting the SharePoint Timer Service, it will solve the purpose.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have your syncronization settings on "use sharepoint profile synchronization".  Even if that is the setting you want, it can not be set to that until you create the sync connection.  Go to Ctrl Admin, Manage Service Applications, (your User profile Service Name), Configure Synchronization settings and change it to Use SharePoint Active Directory Import. Then you can do what you need to do and put it back.

Answer (score 0):

On the Manage Profile Service page, in the Synchronization section, click Configure Synchronization Settings. On the Configure Synchronization Settings page, in the Synchronization Options section, select the Use SharePoint Active Directory Import option, and then click OK.

Regards,
Peter